# Cost of flow using exception

Tags: java, performance, exception

Imagine a simple banking application wherein a use case of fund transfer is being realized. While writing transfer fund operation, the programmer/designer has following two options

1. Write an operation to check if there are sufficient funds or not and return a Boolean based on which the subsequent fund transfer option will be carried out. This require creating two function viz. the checkSufficientFunds() and transferFund()
2. Write a single operation which itself checks if the funds are sufficient or not. This will throw an checked Exception  if there are no sufficient funds and calling method have to handle this.

   I understand that this is an oversimplified scenario. My question is, in theory, what are the performance implications (Memory and CPU) of these two approaches? How do they compare?

Comment: If this is about: "What is the performance impact of the exception handling", then I think you should really modify the question (because a banking scenario like this involves *so* many factors). In a complex scenario like this, the exception handling will almost certainly be negligible. A significant performance difference could, however, be caused by the question, if the transaction has to be split in two parts or not....

Comment: Thanks Chris. I already mentioned its a oversimplification of the real scenario :). But yes you sensed it right from design perspective that making two calls will definitely be costly. I wanted to understand the theoretical comparison of "two method calls" vs single method throwing exception assuming there are no remote calls.

Comment: An exception only has a runtime overhead if it is actually caught. Otherwise it's nothing more than a table with from/to PC values (where it is valid), what kind of exception it catches and where the catch block is.

Comment: @Santosh: No, sorry, that's not what I said ("making two calls will definitely be costly"). I said: Splitting the *transaction* in two parts *can* be costly. Simply *calling* two functions (or maybe a dozen functions) doesn't make any significant difference - except if you're planning to handle a million requests per second on a single machine (which will most probably fail due to other limitations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference in the current JVMs should be negligible. However, stick to the rule that exceptions should be used in exceptional situations. It is a normal flow not to have sufficient funds, so I would use a method `public boolean transferFund()` that returns `true` if successful, and `false` otherwise. This suggestion violates the [command/query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation), but I think it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The performance impact is unlikely to get great enough to worry about.  However, I would still recommended using Exception for exceptional situations.  In this case you don't need two methods.  You can have

```
boolean transferred = transferFundsIfAvailable( ... );
```

A reason using two methods is undesirable is that it could cause race conditions, even if the individual methods are thread safe. Say you have

```
if(checkSufficientFunds()) {
    // another thread transfers funds
    transferFund(); // but there is not enough any more
}
```

Also you could forget to call the check first.  You are better off without it.

Comment: You'll always have to check if sufficient funds are available; it only changes where the race condition occurs.

Comment: A single method call `transferFundsIfAvailable()` can be made thread safe as required, making two calls makes it harder to avoid race conditions reliably.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what you said originally. There's likely to be multiple method calls in the other location as well. All I'm saying is that collapsing two methods into one, besides not necessarily being doable, isn't _intrinsically_ more thread-safe.

Comment: I agree you have to do more than just collapse two methods into one.  You still have the make that method thread safe. However if you have two methods and they are individually thread safe, this is not enough.

Comment: Obviously, but not really related to the OP's question. All I'm still saying is that with your original statement there's a misleading implication that using a single method eliminates race conditions.

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, try-catch blocks doesn't significantly affect performance. Only when an exception occurs and in theses cases you must handle the exception anyway. But you have to use exceptions only when they are required (when the app is unable to preceeed normally).

Answer (score 0):

This assignment is more about atomic operations.  In the first scenario it is possible to overdraft an account whereas in the second you roll everything back (or should).

In terms of performance any time you generate a stack trace that consumes memory and time.  Iirc it makes an execution path 70x more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing a code-review and someone motivated the choice between using exceptions vs method calls by performance considerations, I would down-mark that developer. It's a text-book case of sub-optimization and a waste of time. Optimize where it matters and has a measurable impact. Don't shave milliseconds at the cost of code quality and robustness.

As for this case - some people like to use exceptions as a flow-control mechanism. I don't. Exceptions, in my view, are used to indicate reaching an unexpected state. Often, this is analogous to an error. Checked exceptions imply that the state is something that could conceivably be recovered from within the scope of the current transaction or conversition. An unchecked exception implies that there is no reliable recovery and the system should alert the user.